# SymPy: How to handle Union and ImageSet

Tags: python, set, sympy

I'm new to SymPy and `solveset`. I'm looking for the singularity of an expression and for that I solve the denominator. Afterwards I want to use the results for further calculations to generate a code which deals with the singularity cases.

The return of 'solveset' divers between different equations. In my case up to now:

- `sets.FiniteSet`
- `sets.Union`

While `FiniteSet` can be used directly with for-loops, the `Union` can not.

For example:

```py
sol = Union(ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + pi/2), Integers), ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + 3*pi/2), Integers))
```

If I put this into a loop (`for s in sol:`), the loop will never end. So this is useless. The `sol.is_interval` results to `False` while I expect a `True`.

Observe the following example which detects a not allowed input:

```py
def fun(x):
    if (x+pi/2)%pi == 0:
        print('Detect a not allowed input.')
```

where the `if`-condition must be derived from the solution `sol` from above.

1. How can I determine if `Union` has a finite or infinite number elements?
2. And how can I get one expression which is usable outside of this Set world?

---

This chart explains what I want to do:

[image]

The dark blue part on the left side is the code generator of the light blue part on the right side which can be a different programming language which is not able to handle things like infinity or division by zero. The dark blue part I am going to implement.

Currently I stuck on the block "generation of
Singularity handling", because the `Set` and there especially the `Union` are nice for printing but difficult if not useless for further processing.

I tried to involve `solveset` because of the statement [at SymPy's documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html?highlight=solve#module-sympy.solvers), that *"sooner or later the solveset will take over solve either internally or externally"*. Relating to my application I hope, this will not happen. Maybe I did not fully understand the mechanism of `sets`.

Side notes:

- I also did not find a way to extract only one `ImageSet` hold in this `Union`. It looks for me that I can pack it but unpacking is not foreseen. But from my point of view this is essential for computing.

Comment: BTW solve rather than solveset can be more useful in some situations. It solves both your problems 1 and 2 but at the expense of not being able to handle infinite sets properly

Comment: Hello Oscar - nice to meet you again. Yes you are right. I should move on with `solve`. This also gives me the option to chose the form of return value and I like the dictionary one :).

Comment: I don't see how SymPy will ever be able to remove `solve`. Maybe one day it could be reimplemented on top of `solveset` but there will always be situations where the `solve` API is preferable. Does this basically answer your question then?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin: It does :)

Answer (score 1):

Your specific questions 1 and 2 are both good questions that I don't think SymPy (yet) has an answer to.

I'll try to answer the other part though. If I understand correctly your function `fun` is intended to reject solutions `x` where `(x+pi/2)%pi == 0`. Another way to put that is that you want to *exclude* solutions of the form `x = n*pi + pi/2` for integer `n`. We can express that as a set and then exclude it from the result of solveset:

```
In [7]: _n = Symbol('_n', integer=True)                                                                                                                       

In [8]: sol = Union(ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + pi/2), Integers), ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + 3*pi/2), Integers))                                         

In [9]: sol                                                                                                                                                   
Out[9]: 
⎧         π         ⎫   ⎧         3⋅π         ⎫
⎨2⋅π⋅_n + ─ | _n ∊ ℤ⎬ ∪ ⎨2⋅π⋅_n + ─── | _n ∊ ℤ⎬
⎩         2         ⎭   ⎩          2          ⎭

In [10]: exclude = ImageSet(Lambda(_n, _n*pi + pi/2), Integers)                                                                                               

In [11]: exclude                                                                                                                                              
Out[11]: 
⎧       π         ⎫
⎨π⋅_n + ─ | _n ∊ ℤ⎬
⎩       2         ⎭

In [12]: sol - exclude                                                                                                                                        
Out[12]: 
⎛⎧         π         ⎫   ⎧       π         ⎫⎞   ⎛⎧         3⋅π         ⎫   ⎧       π         ⎫⎞
⎜⎨2⋅π⋅_n + ─ | _n ∊ ℤ⎬ \ ⎨π⋅_n + ─ | _n ∊ ℤ⎬⎟ ∪ ⎜⎨2⋅π⋅_n + ─── | _n ∊ ℤ⎬ \ ⎨π⋅_n + ─ | _n ∊ ℤ⎬⎟
⎝⎩         2         ⎭   ⎩       2         ⎭⎠   ⎝⎩          2          ⎭   ⎩       2         ⎭⎠
```

Unfortunately at this point SymPy isn't really simplifying things the way that it should (and `simplify` doesn't help). Ideally `sol` would simplify to `exclude` in the first place so that subtracting the two would gives the empty set but I guess that isn't implemented yet...

Comment: I add further explanation of my goals. Maybe this helps to understand my issue.